# how to convert nvarchar to decimal value

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

i have created a table for educational information .one of it's field is for AverageMark and so i have set it's datatype to Decimal(2,2)-(for example marks such as: 18.21 , 20, 15.50 ,...).
but i don't know whether is this datatype is correct or sould be changed ?

because when i want to insert into database from Asp.net an exception always thrown which is like below:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Average", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(Average.Text.Trim());
```

and the exception is : **Error converting data type numeric to decimal.**

i don't konw what to do now to insert marks with only 2 decimal value?

Comment: `decimal(2,2)` can contain a maximum of 2 digits, and 2 of those digits should be to the right of the decimal point. Perhaps you intended to use `decimal(4,2)`? (Because none of your example numbers fit the first definition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this code - based on `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

```
Convert.ToDecimal(Average.Text.Trim(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```